# Magento 2 Home Page Slider in Page Builder is not responsive

Tags: magento2, css, home, slider

I’m encountering issues with the Home page slider from the Magento page builder. It is not scaling well to mobile screens. The arrows don’t stay centered and it leaves too much white space around the slider. This way I lose too much of our screen surface.

Part of the problem comes from the min-height set in the page builder itself. Without setting this though, the slide only shows a part of the image. I need it to show fully (resized).

Has anyone else encountered these issues in Magento 2.4.3? Are there already fixes out there?

Thanks!

[homepage screenshot pagebuilder slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gr6dy.png)

Answer (score 0):

did you try Page Builder Slider? over there two different upload slider options available, first is desktop size and second is mobile size banner.
[image]